# Post Image with ajax in laravel 5.6

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I want to create an upload adapter for ckeditor,

I have an issue in my laravel ajax application,

here is my code.

```
export default class UploadAdapter {
    constructor(loader) {
        this.loader = loader;
    }

   upload() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let data = new FormData();
        data.append('upload', this.loader.file);


        $.ajax({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            },
            url: '/loadImage',
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            dataType: 'json',
            async:false,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data.get('upload'));
            },
            error: function (request, status, error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
     });
   }
}
```

I stuck in responding with ajax to laravel controller.

Here is my Controller function:

```
       try {
            $file = $request->file('upload');

            $uploader = MediaUploader::fromSource($file);
            $uploader->setAllowedMimeTypes(['image/jpeg', 'image/gif', 'image/png']);
            $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif']);
            $media = $uploader->upload();

            return response()->json([
                'uploaded' => true,
                'url' => $media->getUrl()
            ]);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return response()->json(
                [
                    'uploaded' => false,
                    'error' => [
                        'message' => $e->getMessage()
                    ]
                ]
            );
        }
```

Here is my error

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at parse (<anonymous>)
    at ajaxConvert (app.js:11826)
    at done (app.js:12294)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (app.js:12587)
```

What is the error in my code ???

I cant get the file information in laravel controller..

How can i solve this issue...? Help me Please!!!

Comment: Do you have the stack trace of this error?

Comment: I updated whole error report?

Comment: This is an error before or after you send the request? You can check it looking at the network tab of your chrome devtools / firebug.

Comment: Can you examine the raw response from the server using your console and make sure it's sending you valid json back?

Comment: I checked request in network tab. Request Status code is 200, and in Request payload there are info of my image file.

Comment: Please update your question with the code of the controller

Comment: @user3158900 Can you give more guidance? How I can examine the raw response from server

Comment: It depends on your browser but if you are using chrome, just hit F12 to open the console, click on the Network tab, and then click on the XHR filter.  That will show you ajax requests.  If you click on the request being made, you should be able to see a preview of the response.

Comment: I do that @user3158900 in fifth comment buddy...

Comment: @FelippeDuarte, I think my problem is related to success call section in ajax, what the hell in Formdata object structure for post file ?

Comment: `data.get('upload')` shouldn't be `data.upload`?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/get

Comment: OK but this data is a response, not the FormData. Replace `success: function (data) {` with `success: function (response) {` and check again.

Comment: I do it but nothing change

Comment: You aren't doing that though, when you set the dataType to `json` it instructs jquery to manually convert the response you get form the server into json.  You need to catch it before it does that so you need to look at the actual response from the server.  Your error is indicating the response from the server is not `json` so if you actually look at what the response is, you can see what the problem is

Answer (score 0):

You have data - empty

```
JSON.parse(''); // SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
```

Add verification:

```
data = data != "" ? $.parseJSON(data) : {};
```

Comment: No dude, I checked it by             console.log(data.get('upload'));
It is not empty Formdata object